# C Programming integer

Tags: c, loops, integer

I need to make a blackjack program. The thing is, as you can see in the code, there's a loop for generating cards without repetition..

If I hit a key it'll print a line like:
"5-diamond"
then hit another key and for example it prints:
"8-clover"

So how do I add those two together without messing up with the code. Since I want to check the value of the sum of those two. What do I need to do?

```
int cards()
{
    int card[51];
    int used[51];

    int x = 0;
    int playerhand = 0;
    int dealerhand = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    while(!kbhit())
        x++;

    srand(x % 100000);

    for(int i = 0; i <= 51; i++)
        used[i] = 0;

    for(;;)
    {
        int w;
        do
        {
            w = rand() % 52;
        }
        while(used[w] == 1);

        used[w] = 1;

        int value = w % 13 + 1;

        if(value >= 2 && value <= 10)
            printf("%d-", value);
        else
        {
            if(value == 1)
                printf("Ace ");
            if(value == 11)
                printf("Jack ");
            if(value == 12)
                printf("Queen ");
            if(value == 13)
                printf("King ");
        }

        int suit = (int)(w / 13);

        if(suit == 0)
            printf("Clover");
        if(suit == 1)
            printf("Spade");
        if(suit == 2)
            printf("Heart");
        if(suit == 3)
            printf("Diamond");

        printf("\n");
        getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain your desired output by giving examples.

Comment: The first `for` loop should be `for(int i=0;i<51;i++)`, not `for(int i=0;i<=51;i++)` and `w=rand()%52;` should be `w=rand()%51;`.

Comment: @Cool Guy: that's correct from a programming standpoint, but as I never saw a blackjack game with only 51 cards, it's probably more appropriate to advise on extending the card arrays to 52 elements and leave the rest as it was...

Comment: I just need to know how to add two values if the program prints two values from the card randomizer. Like what I wrote as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should compute the `sum` of the values and the count of Aces.

If a card is an Ace, add `11`, if it is a King, Queen or Jack, add `10`, otherwise add `value`.

If the `sum` is greater than `21` and you saw Aces, deduct `10` for each Ace until you fall back below `22`.